How to combine Flutter JS interop and Provider
I have a Flutter application that uses Provider for state management.
Recently I have the need to embed my Flutter application in an iFrame and call a dart function using javascript.
Typically to do this you would setProperty(window, 'update', allowInterop(Controller.update));
The issue I am having is that the allowInterop function requires that the function provided is a function or static method in a class. But since my function is within a class that extends ChangeNotifier I can't simply just make the class I want to use static. This is because the class within my Provider calls notifyListeners() which can't be called from a static method.
How can I call my Provider method using Javascript in Flutter?
I tried creating a global class with static methods but this means that none of my data that is listening to changes would update.
I tried removing the requirement for Provider but then state management becomes significantly harder.

I was able to achieve this by using the navigator key and calling my Provider using that key.
@JS('update')
static Future<Model> update() async {
  ModelController modelController = Provider.of<ModelController>(
   navigatorKey.currentContext!,
   listen: false,
);
  return modelController.updateLesson();
}

This solution might cause issues in the future as it is not guaranteed that the navigatorKey has context because the app might not be initialized. I can see this being an issue if the app becomes too big when loading and the Providers haven't been initialized or if the javascript function is immediately called when the website loads.
This is a short term fix for now but a better long term fix would be to use a state management package that is not dependent on the widget tree like get x.
